# なぜnumberが0,1,3となるのでしょうか？

Tags: python, python3

x(0)を実行すると、0,1,3と表示されます。numberを0,1,2にするにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

```
def x(number):
  list = [0,1,2]
  for i in list:
    number+=i
    print(number)
```

Comment: 単に`0,1,2`と表示するだけなら`number`も使わずに`list`の値を順番に表示するだけ、でも出来てしまう気がするので、例えば`f(1)`, `f(2)`など別の数字を指定した場合にはどんな結果になって欲しいのか、関数の仕様を言葉で詳しく説明してもらうとよいかもしれません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

こんばんは。元のコードの中に変数の値を確認するprint文を入れて実行してみました。

```
>>> def x(number):
    list=[0, 1, 2]
    for i in list:
        print("number={}, i={}".format(number, i))
        number += i
        print("number   +  i   = {}\n".format(number))


>>> x(0)

    number=0, i=0
    number   +  i   = 0

    number=0, i=1
    number   +  i   = 1

    number=1, i=2
    number   +  i   = 3

>>>
```

どうでしょうか？　変数の挙動がわかりましたでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

お疲れ様です。

ちょっと、面白すぎですね。
一瞬、まじめに考えてしまいました。

x(0)とした場合の動作ですよね。
number += i
としているから、当然だと思います。
この行がいらない？？？？？
？？？？と書きましたが、これが回答です。

少し、心理的に誘導される質問で、面白かったです。

Comment: あははは。私もまんまと誘導されてしまいました。だめだな、思考が硬質化してる。。